# PHP: Prevent json_encode from converting float to int

Tags: php, json

I need to pass the amount in the form of decimals as in 50.00 to an API but when the amount is json_encoded it converts the amount to int 50.

Sample code:

```
echo json_encode(['amount' => 50.00]);
```

This displays

> {"amount":50}

I need the amount to stay as 50.00 itself. How do I do this?

Comment: But 50.00 and 50 are the same number, if you wanted 50.00, you may need to encode it as a string.

Comment: Agreed, why does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` flag to make sure, that float values are always encoded as a float value. Note, that this option is available starting from PHP 5.6.6.

```
<?php
echo json_encode(['amount' => 50.00], JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
?>
```

Note, that although `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` is an option, the result (as @NigelRen mentioned in the comment) is `50.0`, not `50.00`.

Comment: This still gives `{"amount":50.0}`